# how to enable permission for support web address on android 12 and above

Tags: flutter, manifest, deep-linking

deep links don't work on android 12

I have set the manifest file

````
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data
          android:scheme="https"
          android:pathPrefix="/ad/"
          android:host="Mysite domain" />
      </intent-filter>```

I also created the .well-known/assetlinks.json on my server and added the sha256_cert_fingerprints and packagename 
**deeplinking works fine on android 9 but on android 12 I have to enable the  permission for support web address manually from settings **
````